# Converting 24Bit/96kHz FLAC

Tags: file-conversion

I buy a lot of music in FLAC format and i usually import it into iTunes using 'Fluke' then convert it to Apple Lossless. My friend has ripped a vinyl for me at 24Bit/96kHz and FLAC encoded it. When i try converting it into other formats it basically maximizes it by a ridiculous amount and is just a mess of distortion. Does anyone know some software or a technique of getting these files into a more manageable format while still preserving it's quality?

Comment: Could by a byte flip issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried pulling it in to [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) and exporting it into a new format? The software is free, and it can handle FLAC files. I don't really understand what's going on in the conversion process you're using from iTunes, but it would be worth trying a different piece of software.

Comment: Every time i load Audacity it crashes, i think it is a plug-in problem. However i have tried opening them in Ableton and exporting and it works so i got there in the end. It's a pain having to convert each one separately though. Still, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I am a fan of dBPowerAmp Batch Converter for my audio transcoding needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert any FLAC to AIF ( for iTunes ) with the free XLD application. XLD is also an excellent ripper, slightly better-sounding than iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Max](http://sbooth.org/Max/) to convert from FLAC [I've tried up to 24bit/96 KHz] directly to Apple Lossless [which handles 24/96].

Answer (score 0):

I use Foobar 2000 and have never had any issues decoding from FLAC. To be honest I end up doing most of my transcoding / compression stuff through there. It's free and reasonably powerful, though Windows-only.